# cretae and deploy package in dynamic crm 2015

Tags: crm

I have a little doubt in deploying package.

I have attached my solution by making it zip and add this in Pkgfolder.
Now after build my package, I am adding that .dll where PackageDeployer.exe resides, and then tried to run PackageDeployer.exe

all done successfully 
but in last this PackageDeployer.log generated.

Can you please help me?

Comment: What *PackageDeployer.log*? And what errors are in there? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: You need to copy/ add the `.dll` files before you create a package and you also need to add that in the wizard you are using.. after creating package you can not add .DLL file!!!